# what is the best way to push a review for 2 consecutive merge commits?

Tags: git

I have a local topic branch named "branchT" which made 2 consecutive merge with a remote master branch named "branchM", how could I get the merge commit pushed to gerrit for review which contains everything in my "branchT" including the 2 merge results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You really should not use merge with gerrit. From my point, `git reabse` is the friend of gerrit.

Trust me, merge will make your gerrit totally mess.

You can describe your question more detail, now I can not give your more good suggestions.

Br,
Tim